# react-native-chart-kit Pie chart any modification or any property

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-chart-kit, react-native-svg-charts

[image]

In react-native-chart-kit Pie chart is there any property or modification to set legend like this?? and also click to show tooltip ?.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I have set haslegend={false} and shown this data in the view from the array.